# how to convert docx to pdf in asp.net without MS office installed on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to ask is there any way we can convert .docx files into PDFs without MS office installed on my server?

Is there any adobe SDK which can help me to perform this action in ASP.NET?

If there is any free (open source) API please let me know, or any paid which help to achieve this solution?

But first of all is any thing from Adobe to get the solution?

Comment: My basic question is, is there any Adobe SDK which can help to get this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can install `PDF/XPS exporter`

Link : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7

Sample code (Javascript)

```
var filename = "...\\Test.docx";
var msword = WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application");
msword.Visible = false;
msword.WindowState = 2; // minimized
msword.Documents.Open(filename);
msword.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(filename + ".pdf", 17); // 17 is the magic number for wdFormatPDF
msword.quit();
```

Comment: I will be very surprised if this solution works without MS office installed.

Comment: Hello,
does your code require MS office to be installed on machine?

Comment: you must have Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, You can also use aspose;  http://asposewords.codeplex.com/

Comment: My basic question is, is there any Adobe SDK which can help to get this solution?

Comment: yes i know but my answer don't need install component or other , you just eed to use assembly in the GAC, but you can use aspose , it's omplicated solution relative to first

Comment: is there any Adobe SDK which we can use for this?

Comment: i get following error message when i try to access this page.
"Sorry, this page is not available"

Comment: Adjust you filepath var filename = "...\\Test.docx";

Comment: livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk is this SDK can be used to convert Word Doc into pdf? and does this SDK dont need MS office to be installed?

Comment: any suggestion regard this?
livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk does this SDK can be used to convert Word Doc into pdf? and does this SDK dont need MS office to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any opensource library capable of doing this. I'm currently using [Aspose.Words for .Net](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx). It's not for free, but it can be used to build the word docs, too.  I originally bought it to just do this kind of conversion (it was the fastest library that I was able to find, and the one producing the best looking pdf's).

Comment: My basic question is, is there any Adobe SDK which can help to get this solution?

Comment: I don't think so. Acrobat relies on Word for converting docs to pdf. It adds commands on the ribbon, or you can use it as a virtual printer, but office is needed to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try one of these 2 solutions to achieve what you want.

1. Image Magic: http://www.imagemagick.org
   This is free but to find the correct syntax could be a challenge.

---

2. OfficeToPdf: http://www.a-pdf.com/office-to-pdf/index.htm This ($49) library is easy-to-use but requires MS Office installed:

   `OfficeToPDF "c:\help.doc" "c:\output\help.pdf"`

Comment: Does OfficeToPDF require MS Office installed?